# Blob Url for Audio element is working for http, but, not working for https

Tags: html, reactjs, html5-audio

The following is part of a React.js component

```
const response = await fetch(path, { 
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ avatarId: currentAvatar, text })
});
```

```
const responseBlob = await response.blob()
```

```
const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(responseBlob);
setUrl(objectURL);
```

```
<audio id="audioclip" controls>
  <source src={url} type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

The Blob url is being loaded for http (working for localhost), but, it is not being loaded for "https" in production site.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The above code is working in http://localhost:3000. The audio blob url is loaded correctly in development.
But, the same is not working in production site with https. I tried in Chrome browser.

Comment: This issue is related to AWS API Gateway. I have updated API Gateway Settings by adding media types to Binary Media Types section and redeployed the API. It fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is related to AWS API Gateway. I have updated API Gateway Settings by adding media types to Binary Media Types section and redeployed the API. It fixed the issue.

Binary Media Types Added:

audio/mpeg
text/html